# Function that accepts any type of Measurement in swift

Tags: swift, polymorphism

Swift implements the `Measurement` type which can be used to hold values such as speeds, altitudes, etc. in their desired metric.

For example:

```swift
// Going to explicitly type here so the question is clear

var speed: Measurement<UnitSpeed> = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitSpeed.metersPerSecond)
var altitude: Measurement<UnitLength> = Measurement(value: 500, unit: UnitLength.meters)

altitude.convert(to: UnitLength.feet)

print("500 meters is roughly \(Int(altitude.value)) feet")
// Prints: 500 meters is roughly 1640 feet
```

However, even though `UnitLength` and `UnitSpeed` are both subclasses of `Unit`, measurements using these types can not be passed in polymorphically into a function in swift.

For example, the following function does not work if you pass in an object of type `Measurement<UnitLength>` or `Measurement<UnitSpeed>`.

```swift
func formatMeasurementAsString(measurement: Measurement<Unit>) -> String {
    return "\(Int(measurement.value)) \(measurement.unit.symbol)"
}
```

Passing in either `speed` or `altitude` defined above into this function yields the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Measurement<UnitSpeed>' to expected argument type 'Measurement<Unit>'`

EDIT:

So you can explicitly type both `speed` and `altitude` in this example as type `Measurement<Unit>`. However, if you do this, they lose the incredibly useful `.convert(to:)` function unless you typecast them back into `Measurement<UnitLength>` before converting, which is not very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but just so you know, a function like `formatMeasurementAsString` defeats 99% of the benefit of Measurement, namely, the use of `MeasurementFormatter`

Comment: Thanks @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I will look into that!

Comment: Just so you know, be *really* careful about accidentally encoding assumptions about formatting into your code. In this case, you're encoding the assumption that units should be printing in Arabic numerals with commas grouping every 3 digits, followed by a space, followed by the English name of the unit. This is wrong in the majority of the world. MeasurementFormatter implements all the nuanced and complex localization logic to do this right, for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the function generic

```
func formatMeasurementAsString<T: Unit>(measurement: Measurement<T>) -> String {
    return "\(Int(measurement.value)) \(measurement.unit.symbol)"
}
```

Example

```
let length = Measurement(value: 180.0, unit: UnitLength.meters)
let speed = Measurement(value: 60, unit: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour)

print(formatMeasurementAsString(measurement: length))
print(formatMeasurementAsString(measurement: speed))
```

> 180 m
> 60 km/h